# Convert string to arraylistof object

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have the following String data that contain arraylist of objects data,How can i convert it to arraylist type

```
 String data="[Score{id=1, value='3.5'}, 
  Score{id=2, value='4.5'}, 
  Score{id=3, value='2.0'}]";
```

Comment: Surely one of the thousands of examples of splitting strings will give you the answer.

Comment: `convert it to arraylist type` means? Really sorry but I could not able to get your question. Could you please tell me what will be the expected output?

Comment: I need to convert it to array list of objects it should be List<Score> lists=

Comment: Why not write a regex and iterate through the results, constructing a new `Score` object for every match? http://i.stack.imgur.com/ANh1i.png ; sadly, the string data is a little bit far away from being JSON so you'll have to write your own parsing methods.

Comment: @Ali-Alrabi I think I found what you were looking for. It is complex, but it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would omit the brackets [] at start by cutting out the first and last character. Then you have to split the String to get all the objects in an array. At the end you have to convert the String objects to the actual `Score` classes. You can do that by the same principle, using `substring` and `indexOf` methods.

In terms of code, this would look something like this:

```
// the String containing all the objects
String data="[Score{id=1, value='3.5'}, Score{id=2, value='4.5'}, Score{id=3, value='2.0'}]";

// Cutting out the brackets []
data = data.substring(1, data.length - 1);

// Splitting the String to smaller pieces
// like "Score{id=1, value='3.5'}", etc
String[] array = data.split(",");

// Creating the ArrayList, where we will save the scores
List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {

  // Creating the Score instance
  Score score = new Score();

  // Omitting the brackets {}
  int start = array[i].indefOx("{") + 1;
  int end = array[i].indefOx("}");

  // Cutting out the String inside brackets {}
  String temp = array[i].substring(start, end);

  // We use the same principles again to get those values inside the brackets {}.
  String[] tempArray = temp.split(",");
  for(int j=0;j<tempArray.length;j++) {
    int start = array[i].indefOx("=") + 1;
    temp2 = tempArray[j].substring(start);
    if(j == 0) {
      score.setId(Integer.valueOf(temp2));
    } else {
      // To cut out the ''
      score.setValue(temp2.substring(1, temp2.length));
    }
  }

  // adding score instance to the list
  scores.add(score);

}
```

I would just point out that you would have to verify I used the right indexes, when I used `substring` and `indexOf`. If this String would be without the "Score" substring, you would be able to convert this more easily, because then the String would represent a `JSONArray`.